# Restrict user from viewing other subsites

Tags: permissions, 2016, site, sub-site

Is there a way I can restrict the users to see other sub-sites that they don't have access to in Site Contents or Quick Links?

**Example:**

- Employee A = has access to Sub-site A, B and C. Should not see D/E/F
- Employee B = has access to Sub-site D, E and F. Should not see A/B/C

I understand that if user doesn't have permission to a certain site then he/she will get to a 'tell us why you need access' page but the requirement is to make it not visible. *(it's like we only want the user know these are the only sites available)*

Comment: In Quick Links, you can set target audience to links from site settings-->Navigation settings.

Answer (score 0):

If navigation will be automatic then the security trimming should remove the links to the subsite that user don't have access. If you create navigation manually you need to look at the audience targeting to show\hide entries per audience.